# Using RAID on DELL Precision 3640

Tags: raid, kubuntu

I'm used to install kubuntu 18.04 on Dell precision **3630** since some time, on that system, I activate a RAID-1, all is working, I've done this on at least 10 computers, with UEFI.

We recently got Dell precision **3640** computers, on that systems, the RAID-1 configuration is the same, but when installing, the installer does not see the RAID array, I've got the error:

```
ubi.partman return error -141
```

The RAID-1 is provided by "Intel RST RAID DRIVER", the uefi configuration set accordingly :

- sata harddrive are in RAID mode
- raid-1 creation is done in uefi menu "Device configuration"

I started a console when installing to search in `/dev`, and I don't see any `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb` nor something looking like raid array `/dev/dm*`.

I started a Windows 10 installation to see if the problem was linked to kubuntu or not, and it seems that Windows is able to deal with the RAID.

To dig a little more, I try kubuntu 20.04 and debian buster, with the same result: RAID is not seen by linux.

- Did I miss something?
- How can I install theses distribution with RAID-1?

Comment: What kind of RAID (hardware, software or fakeraid?). What are the BIOS settings set as?

Comment: It's the raid offered by the motherboard: Inter Raid driver, I'm not sure, but I'll qualify it to hardware

Comment: Id be a bit surprised (but its possible) if its hardware RAID.  Can you provide a service tag of one of the systems so I can look up its specs?  My gut tells me you are using "Fake RAID"  Under Linux I'd urge you to turn off fake RAID and use software RAID. Its as performant and more robust.

Comment: Actually, just saw this - "Intel RST RAID DRIVER" - Its fake RAID.  I wouldnt do it but you would want to use the dmraid driver.  Unless you are dual booting this somehow on a new setup you are much better off disabling RAID in BIOS and using mdadm/software RAID.  Its faster, more robust and easier to manage.